# How can I use axios result in res.render in expressjs?

Tags: node.js, express, axios

I don't know how I can use axios response.data in "res.render" in expressjs, I tried to create an Array and transfer axios result into a new array (myWorkspace) and then use Array globally but Array is empty!!

```js
app.get('/fullscreen', passport.isAuthenticated, passport.isAuthorized('user'), (req, res) => {
  var myWorkspace = [];

  axios
    .get('http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces', {
      auth: {
        username: 'admin',
        password: '@dmin9901',
      },
      headers: {
        accept: 'application/json',
        'content-type': 'application/json',
      },
    })
    .then(function(response) {
      myWorkspace.push(response.data['workspaces']);
      return myWorkspace;
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      // handle error
      console.log(error);
    })
    .then(function() {
      // always executed
    });

  res.render('fullscreen', {
    workspace: JSON.stringify(myWorkspace),
  });
});
```

Comment: is `geoserver/rest/workspaces` on the same server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`axios.get` executes asynchronously. Which means the `res.render` method will probably execute before getting the response from API. That's why you got an empty array.

Change to this:

```js
axios.get(...).then(function(response) {
  myWorkspace.push(response.data["workspaces"]);
  res.render('fullscreen', {
    workspace: JSON.stringfy(myWorkspace)
  })
})
```

See below demo:

```js
// simulate axios.get to make a HTTP call
function get() {
  return new Promise((resolve) =>
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve([1, 2, 3]);
    }, 1000),
  );
}

(function controller() {
  var myWorkspace = [];
  get().then((res) => {
    myWorkspace = res;
    console.log('get response:', myWorkspace);
  });
  // res.render will print firstly
  console.log('res.render:', myWorkspace);
})();
```

The execution result:

```sh
res.render: []
get response: [ 1, 2, 3 ]
```

Comment: Hello @slideshowp2, please edit answer add JSON.stringify(myWorkspace) instead of JSON.stringfy(myWorkspace)